# Convert auth config from apache http server 2.2 to apache 2.4

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, apache2, httpd.conf

I have the following apache 2.2 configuration and need to transform it to apache 2.4.

```
<Location />
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny From Env=TEST
        Allow From Env=LOCAL
        Allow From Env=WHITELIST
</Location>
```

The idea is to only allow access to requests with LOCAL or WHITELIST env variable set when the env TEST is set.

However trying to convert it to something like the following does not return the same result:

```
<Location />
    <RequireAll>
        Require env LOCAL
        Require env WHITELIST
        Require not env TEST
    </RequireAll>
</Location>
```

I guess this is because *[negated authorization directives are unable to return a successful result](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#requireall)* but in that case I cannot find any exact equivalent config...

Comment: The "require not" would not be implicit (no need to specify it)? can something in TEST be also included in LOCAL?

Comment: Unfortunately not. There is reason behind each env variable.

Comment: What I mean is, If no values are inside each others variables you could just use ¨Require not env TEST¨ only, or just ¨Require env LOCAL , Require env WHITELIST¨, everything not specified is denied so why deny something specifically along with what's approved if it is already denied without specification?